# MySQL query involving cross join, uniqueness, etc

Tags: sql, mysql, join

Thankfully, I haven't had to work with particularly complex SQL queries before. Here's my goal.

I have the table `hams`, which I would like to cross-join with the table `eggs` - that is, get all ham-egg combinations... to an extent.

The `eggs` table also has an attribute `how_cooked`, which is defined as `ENUM('over-easy','scrambled','poached')`. **I would like a resultset listing every possible combination of ham and egg-cooking method, along with a sample egg cooked that way.** (I don't care which egg in particular.)

So if 3 hams with `id` of 1, 2, and 3, and 3 eggs of each cooking method, my resultset should look something like this:

```
+---------+-----------------+---------+
| hams.id | eggs.how_cooked | eggs.id |
+---------+-----------------+---------+
| 1       | over-easy       | 1       |
| 1       | scrambled       | 4       |
| 1       | poached         | 7       |
| 2       | over-easy       | 1       |
| 2       | scrambled       | 4       |
| 2       | poached         | 7       |
| 3       | over-easy       | 1       |
| 3       | scrambled       | 4       |
| 3       | poached         | 7       |
+---------+-----------------+---------+
```

I'm sure I could hack together some solution with loads of subqueries here and there, but is there any elegant way to do this is MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through a bit of thinking real hard and Googling, I may have found a good solution:

```
SELECT * FROM hams, eggs GROUP BY hams.id, eggs.how_cooked
```

It seems to work. Is it really that easy?

Comment: It works, yes, but only because you `don't care which egg in particular`. SQL behavior for selecting columns not in a `GROUP BY` isn't well-defined. However, in my experience, it always returns a valid value. Also, this'll only work as long as `eggs` contains at least one occurrence of each value in the enum (of course, it looks like this is a pretty safe assumption).

Comment: Good - I'm glad to know that there are, in fact, well-defined gotchas, since if there weren't any obvious ones, I'm sure obscure ones would show up. Thanks!

Comment: and mysql is afaik the only database that will allow you to do it this way

Comment: Which I believe is wrong, as it tempts you to believe the extraneous data actually relates to the aggregate data specifically.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT hams.id, eggs.how_cooked, eggs.id
FROM hams
  CROSS JOIN eggs
```

This does the trick.  `CROSS JOIN` is synonymous with `,` but has a higher precedence in MySQL .

[MySQL 5.0 Reference - JOIN syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)